# NSString stringWithFormat Percent Sign

Tags: nsstring, stringwithformat

I searched and could not find this answer...

If I have this, how can I get it to display the final % symbol?  It just omits it in my label.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tries %i%", tries];
```

Comment: You have to use the escaping symbol '\' [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tries %i%%", tries];

Comment: Actually, that didnt work, I answered too soon.  This worked Tries %i%%

Comment: ok, edit answer because comment is may be ignore to read.

Answer (score 29):

I thought I could contribute a bit and share **[this comprehensive list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)** of options. Jesse is 
right!

In my case, the following does the trick!

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Progress: %.2f%%", progress*100] 
// progress is float ranging 0.0-1.0, 
//and I would like it to print up to 2 decimal point
```

Happy coding!